Can I share a presentation with a user who doesn't have a Google account so that they can copy and edit it?
I am a teacher and spent much of the summer creating a presentation for my students in Google Slides to use as an assignment.
The intention is that I will share a link to the presentation with students who will each make a copy of it in order to edit it and add content according to instructions within the presentation itself.
Once they have completed the assignment a week later, the students will share a link to their edited presentation with me and I will edit their copy and and grade it.
Is it possible to do this if a student does not have a Google account?

There is a workaround :
You need to create / duplicate the files & give them the link to the file with permissions set to "Anyone with link can edit"
Simply click Share on the file then change the settings accordingly .

This answer could be improved with more detailed instructions

The student will need to have a GOOGLE account.   It does not matter whether the name of this account is   johnny.student@gmail.come   or johnny.student@someOtherMail.com
But they must have a Google account, and that Google account must know where to find your slideshop
